# Java ADT calling variables

Tags: java, adt, instantiation

I'm new to Java and I'm trying to create an ADT. My ADT involves creating and processing fractions through input of a numerator and denominator. I want one of my methods to add two fractions together and return a simplified fraction based on the gcd of the two sums. The problem I'm having is with instantiating the components of the two fractions(the numerator and denominator). The method should take a fraction other, denoted `public Rational add(Rational other)`. The first variables I assigned were

```
int d1 = this.denominator;
int d2 = other.denominator;
```

but this doesn't seem to work. Below is the method thus far:

```
public Rational add(Rational other){
  int d1 = this.denominator;
  int d2 = other.denominator;
  int dtotal = d1*d2;
  int n1 = this.numerator*d2;
  int n2 = other.numerator*d1;
  int ntotal = n1+n2;
  if(ntotal>dtotal){
    for(int i=1; i<=ntotal; i++){
      if(ntotal%i==0 && dtotal%i==0){
        gcd=i;
      }
    }
  }else if(dtotal>ntotal){
    for(int i=1;i<=dtotal;i++){
      if(dtotal%i==0 && ntotal%i==0){
        gcd=i;
      }
    }
  }else if(dtotal==ntotal){
    gcd=numerator;
  }
  numerator = ntotal/gcd;
  denominator = dtotal/gcd;
}
```

Comment: can you provide code snippet you have written?

Comment: I've edited the question to include the entire method. I think I should also mention that I have instantiated the numerator, denominator, and gcd outside the methods as `int numerator;`, `int denominator;` and `int gcd;`

Comment: Did you define the member variable `denominator` and `numerator` in your `Rational` class.

Comment: Can you provide the complete class. Because after adding these member variable I am not getting any compile error.

Comment: I've added the entire class thus far

Comment: why have you defined an interface inside an class. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want the class to implement the given interface - I just want to create an ADT that can take a fraction and be able to do things with it. I'm new to both Java and ADT's so I'm not familiar with the conventions of building an ADT. I just realized that I was supposed to add `implements Rational` to the class declaration, sorry for the rookie mistake!

Comment: You should really look into Euclid's algorithm for calculating the GCD. Moreover, do it at just one place; don't copy the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your interface outside of the class with the required methods. Here is the sample, please edit as per your needs.

```
interface Rational {    
  public int getNumerator();
  public int getDenominator();
  public Rational add(Rational other);
  public Rational multiply(Rational other);
  public int compareTo(Rational other);
}
```

Now your class should be defined like this:

```
public class RationalC implements Rational {

  int gcd;
  int numerator;
  int denominator;


  @Override
  public int getNumerator() {
    return numerator;
  }

  @Override
  public int getDenominator() {
    return denominator;
  }

  @Override
  public Rational add(Rational other) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public Rational multiply(Rational other) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(Rational other) {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Add your `add`, `multiply` method definition. Use the `getNumerator()` and `getDenominator()` to access the values instead of directly accessing them.

Comment: Oh okay that makes things much simpler. Thank you for the help!